# TYPO3: what USER_INT means?

Tags: typo3

Could anyone explain to me what is the meaning of USER_INT in typo3?  I know it somehow disables cache for a plugin but I don't get why it is called "USER_INT" (especially the INT part is confusing). Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell me the reason for downvote, please?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this forum thread: http://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=476052&  I'm not sure where the poster is getting the information from, but it looks like anything using `_INT` is somehow related to *internal handling*...

Comment: Thank you! After reading the post of Jinga and thinking some more, I'll go for "The name does not make sense". I tried to understand Typo a bit more but this is not the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That are historic names. Afair it has to do with different ways to include php-scripts. There are some more things like "tt_content" ("typo table"). Do not think too much of it.

_INT means: uncached content. Instead of output there is some placeholder like  in the cached content, so TYPO3 parses these hashes and creates that part of the content on the fly.

That means, if there is one or more placeholders, TYPO3 needs to execute the code for each request. And for that, you probably need to define includeLibs - if you need to load additional scripts.

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum=0
page.30 = USER_INT
page.30 {
  userFunc = user_various->listContentRecordsOnPage
  reverseOrder = 1
  # include these files, before executing user_various->listContentRecordsOnPage
  includeLibs = fileadmin/example/example_callfunction.php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is old question. But, will leave the answer here hoping it will help someone. Will explain it in layman's terms using an example for simplicity.

`USER` is global to all users.
`USER_INT` is user[browser] specific.

The INT stands for 'internal caching' which means TYPO3 does not cache the object.

Example:
Assume `JMC\Ag\Utility\UX\Renderer->a` processes user login, and let's assume a message 'Welcome, ' followed by the user's name upon successful login, will be displayed on the site. The following code will show 'Welcome, John' to everyone browsing the site around the world as soon as I login to my account:

```
__FRAMEWORK {
        postCodefeature.5 = USER
        postCodefeature.5.userFunc = JMC\Ag\Utility\UX\Renderer->a
    }
```

This is because my browsing data will be store in the ***common*** (*general*) user session variable of the site, where everyone browsing the site has access to.

The following code will show 'Welcome, John' ***in my browser only***, once I login to my account:

```
__FRAMEWORK {
        postCodeContentBlock-1.5 = USER_INT
        postCodeContentBlock-1.5.userFunc = JMC\Ag\Utility\UX\Renderer->a
    }
```

This is because my data is now stored in the ***user-specific*** (*browser*) session variable, where only I have access to while browsing the site. Every user of the site gets one.

NOTE: It's not necessary to know where this data is being stored. TYPO3 does that automatically, hence the switches: `USER` and `USER_INT`.